# Tourism hobby clubs in Bahrain

Tags: bahrain

I came to Bahrain last month and am looking for things to do. Currently, I'm taking driving lessons, which are helping to pass some time. Can anybody tell if there are any tourism hobby clubs in Bahrain? Like where you get to go to different places as a group, and make friends in the process. This kind of thing is common in India.